# The type or namespace name 'SQLite' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, sqlite, dll, visual-studio-2012, reference

YES, I have added the System.Data.Sqlite.dll to my project (VS2012).
YES, I have added a reference.
YES, I have doublechecked, that the reference has been created (Reference Properties > Path is correct).
YES, I have used Google, Bing,

NO, I don't know why my code won't compile.

Comment: Rebuild it already? BTW +1 for using `Bing` here :)))

Comment: Do a clean before the rebuild.

Comment: LOL, I did clean and rebuild. I wouldn't be posting here, if I hadn't.

Comment: My website was targeting .NET 4.0.   I was getting your error too.  Changed in Property Pages to target `4.0.3` instead, and the error went away.

Answer (score 11):

If it was installed with nuget, execute the following command in the Package Manager Console :

```
Update-Package –reinstall System.Data.SQLite
```

In VS2013, you can find this console in the menu View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console.

As stated in a comment, this error happens if your project is configured to use Net45 when installing the package and some time after you configure it to use Net40.

I guess that the reverse case, Net40 to Net45 configuration, may also throws this error.

Comment: Also worth noting is that SQLite may not have been installed in the first place. If the above command returns text in red that says that 'SQLite package was not installed in any project' and that the update failed, just go to Manage NuGet Packages For Solution from Tools > NuGet Package Manager and search for System.Data.SQLite. Then select the package and install it for this project. I did that and the error was gone.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you are referencing incorrect version of System.Data.Sqlite.dll that is not compatible with version of .NET you are using in your application.

Try install correct one from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

Comment: This was the correct answer in my case.  I had an assembly that was .NET 4.5, and I had installed SQLite via NuGet.  Then I changed the assembly to .NET 4.0, and the SQLite reference gave me the OP's error.

Answer (score 3):

I had same situation. 
I checked Properties of referenced SQLite dll and version of one throwing error, and it was 1.0.92.0
I replaced it with right one of 1.0.90.0 and *now it's working*.

Surprisingly 1.0.92.0 was working with Web Project but not with either of class library or WCF library prj of VS2013?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the referenced dll is matching the targeted platform of your project. 
E.g: If you are using a 4.0 assembly with a project targeting 4.5 then you will get this error.